# Requirement for having a left-adjoint functor

Tags: category-theory

Let $G : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be a functor between two categories. Suppose for each object $D \in \mathcal{D}$ there is a $C \in \mathcal{C}$ that is the "best approximation" of $D$ in the sense that there is an  $\eta : D \to G(C)$ such that for each arrow $g : D \to G(C')$ we have $G(f)\eta = g$ for a unique $f : C \to C'$.

**Problem:** show that $G$ has a left adjoint.

**My try:** I have defined a functor $F : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ in the obvious way, using the above (i.e. $FD$ is the best approximation of $D$ and for an arrow $g : D \to D'$ we have $Fg$ is the unique $f : FC \to FC'$ such that $G(f)\eta = \eta'g$). This gives a bijection
$$
\mathcal{C}(FD, C) \to \mathcal{D}(D, GC).
$$
But I am having trouble proving that this bijection is natural, i.e., for $\alpha : D \to D'$ and $\beta : C' \to C$, proving that the following diagram commutes.

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{C}(FD,C) @>{m_{D,C}}>> \mathcal{D}(F, GC)\\
@V{\mathcal{C}(F\alpha, \beta)}VV @V{\mathcal{D}(\alpha,G\beta)}VV \\
\mathcal{C}(FD',C') @>{m_{D',C'}}>> \mathcal{D}(F', GC')
\end{CD}$$

Comment: See theorem 19.1 and Exc 19A in http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf

Comment: Also theorem 3.1.5 of *Handook of categorical algebra 1 - Basic category theory* by F. Borceux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although some references are given in comments, I decided to write an answer.

Note, that $m_{D,C}(f)=G(f)\circ\eta_D$ for every morphism $f\colon F(D)\to C$. To show that such diagram is commutative is to prove the equality
$$
(\text{hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(\alpha,G(\beta))\circ m_{D,C})(f)=(m_{D',C'}\circ\text{hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(F(\alpha),\beta))(f)
$$
for every morphism $f\colon F(D)\to C$. Indeed, 
$$
(\text{hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(\alpha,G(\beta))\circ m_{D,C})(f)=\text{hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(\alpha,G(\beta))(m_{D,C}(f))=\text{hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(\alpha,G(\beta))(G(f)\circ\eta_D)= G(\beta)\circ G(f)\circ\eta_D\circ\alpha=G(\beta\circ f)\circ G(F(\alpha))\circ\eta_{D'}=G(\beta\circ f\circ F(\alpha))\circ\eta_{D'}=m_{D',C'}(\beta\circ f\circ F(\alpha))=m_{D',C'}(\text{hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(F(\alpha),\beta)(f))=(m_{D',C'}\circ\text{hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(F(\alpha),\beta))(f),
$$
QED.